# Синтаксический разбор предложения: На уроках запрещено/нельзя разговаривать

Tags: грамматика

*На уроках **запрещено/нельзя разговаривать**.*

Предложение безличное **односоставное или двусоставное**?

***Нельзя*** — модальный предикатив?

***Запрещено*** — краткое причастие с модальным значением. Можно ли считать это слово **модальным предикативом?**

**Вид** сказуемого: составное **глагольное** или составное **именное** (тогда инфинитив в роли дополнения)?

**Помогите ученику** Иванову сделать правильный разбор! А то еще одну двойку получит.

**[Ученик Иванов и модальный предикатив](https://proza.ru/2021/06/18/1111)**

Comment: Это безличные предложения. Вы и сами об этом пишете. В чем проблема?

Comment: Надо ответить на все вопросы, ни в одном из них я не уверена. Особенно по поводу сказуемого.  Ученик  Иванов  посчитал предикатив сказуемым,  а инфинитив дополнение. И главное, вид сказуемого не назвал  И по поводу предикатива сомнения. Это краткое причастие или предикатив?

Comment: См. дополнение ко ответу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш пример относится к безличным предложениям с модальным значением, которое здесь передается с безличными-предикативными словами: нельзя, запрещено.

В Синтаксисе русского языка, Валгина. Н.С. как раз говорится о таких примерах.

В тех случаях, когда причастие имеет модальное значение, сказуемое обязательно включает в себя инфинитив: Для чего мне было предназначено умереть, так же как теперь мне предназначено жить? (Ю. Герм.). Примыкающий инфинитив при форме страдательного причастия имеет либо субъектное, либо объектное значение; в первом случае он включается в сказуемое (в предложениях с устраненным деятелем), во втором — выполняет функцию дополнения (в предложениях с неопределенным деятелем):

**После короткого совещания решено было идти обратно (Шол.);**

**На станции и в вагонах запрещено было зажигать свет (А. Н. Т.).**

**Дополнение.**

Традиционно в таких предложениях выделяют СГС как главный член односоставного предложения. Что касается предикативов, то к ним относят слова, означающие статическое состояние и выступающие в функции главного члена — сказуемого, предиката. К ним относятся и причастия на -то, -но. Напр.: накурено, заперто.

Comment: Может быть, и так.  Но хотелось бы прочитать об этих традициях  в доступной для школьников литературе. У Кустовой и Литневской  я этого не нашла. А вы можете дать ссылку на источник? В словаре: накурено - в знач. сказуемого (предикатив), а заперто, запрещено и  и намусорено в словаре нет.  У Кустовой  это причастия в безличном предложении  (кроме накурено), но совсем не предикативы. Причастия - это глагольные формы, а предикативы - не глагольные.  Статическое состояние - что за термин?

Comment: О предикативах см. Википедию.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Comment: Но ведь страдательное причастие осознает состояние. Используется в роли сказуемого.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ на комментарий**

**Спасибо, Серж,** за ответ и внимание к теме, голос от меня.
И теперь вы за все в ответе))  А вопросов у меня много.

1. **Причастный предикатив** отличается от обычного предикатива или нет?  Можно сравнить: ***запрещено и нельзя***.  У Кустовой причастные модальные формы рассматриваются отдельно от предикативов   в теме безличных предложений.  В словаре указано:  **НЕЛЬЗЯ**, в функц. сказ. (с инф.).  Это обычная характеристика  предикатива. А про причастие ***запрещено*** ничего не сказано. Тогда это **не предикатив**? И вопрос: какие формы мы называем **предикативом** (смысл этого названия какой?)

(2) Командир ***велел*** (что?) ***стрелять***.  Учитель ***велел*** (что?) ***молчать.*** Это объектный инфинитив, не так ли?

Было ***велено***  (что?) ***стрелять/молчать.***  Это уже необъектный инфинитив?

Деятели здесь учитель и командир. И какой  же деятель в причастной форме, **устраненный или неопределённый**?  Странная **терминология** у Валгиной,  я ее не понимаю. У Кустовой ничего такого  нет, а у нее учебник более современный.

3. Кустова не включает безличные формы ***запрещено и нельзя*** в состав  ***СГС***. У нее все варианты перечислены.    У Литневской   их **тоже нет**. У нее сказано:

   ```
   Приинфинитивная часть выражает грамматическое значение 
   сказуемого, а также дополнительную характеристику 
   действия (инфинитива!)  — указание на его начало, 
   середину или конец (фазисное значение) или возможность, 
   желательность, степень обычности и другие характеристики, 
   описывающие отношение  СУБЪЕКТА действия к этому действию 
   (модальное значение).
   ```

Именно **субъекта** действия, то есть того, кто **разговаривает.** Но не говорящий запрещает себе разговаривать, а учитель.  Иначе было бы так: **я не должен разговаривать.**

4. Ученик Иванов четко **объясняет**: запретил кто-то, а разговаривать не должен он. По моему пониманию здесь  **составное именное сказуемое:**   ***запрещено***, связка ***быть*** опущена,  ***разговаривать*** — дополнение (как необходимый структурный элемент безличного предложения).
5. ***Разговаривать было запрещено.***  Предложение двусоставное или односоставное?  Может быть так:  ***разговаривать*** —  подлежащее , ***было запрещено*** —  именное сказуемое? **Порядок** слов влияет на разбор?